# How do i download a driver from windows update?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, windows-update

Unfortunately my manufacture didnt include a wifi driver on their cd. I have to connect via lan and use windows update to get it.

How do i grab the installer/driver from windows update so i can store it on a CD/USB/Partition so i can install it w/o lan next time i format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft Update Catalog](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/) *theoretically* contains all the updates available from Windows Update, in a downloadable form.  In practice it isn't quite 100% coverage but with a bit of luck you'll be right.  You'll need to know just what device you're looking for, and may have to try a few different keywords to get the right one.

Note that you have to use Internet Explorer.

Comment: Incidentally: it might be worth trying the manufacturer's web site first.

Comment: I'll just accept this. I ended up finding the 'details' of the update i installed. I googled a certain part of it and found the manufacturer website and grabbed the driver from there. I still cant believe it isnt on their cd. I also thought i'd have to search realtek (i think but maybe it was another brand) but i didnt. It was the motherboard company